# How to use python or linux command to convert protein ID into protein name by searching in a local database?

Tags: python, linux, search, fasta

I have two files:
ID.txt containing protein IDs, like this:

```
KKP65897.1
KKP42119.1
KKP91065.1
OGY93232.1
```

The other file is nr.faa. It's a database fasta-format file downloaded from NCBI. It's like this:

```
>KKP42119.1 hypothetical protein DDB_G027.......
MASTQNTVEEVAQJML.......
>KKP65897.1 hypothetical protein DDB_G127.......
MATSREEQNTVEEVAQJML.......
```

I want to search in this fasta database file by the name in the IDs.txt, and return the protein names, like 'hypothetical protein', and store them in a txt file. In this way, I will link the ID with the protein name.

The database file is huge ~7G, I also extracted the header lines '> .....' and saved it to a txt file (~3G). Maybe it's faster to search in that file.

How to do this in Python or linux command line?

Thank you.

Comment: maybe load the flat files into an actual relational database like SQLite or MySQL.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't know anything about SQLite or MySQL. Is there a way to do it in python or linux commands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> and return the protein names, like 'hypothetical protein', and store
>   them in a txt file

With powerful **awk** tool:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{ a[$1];next }/^>/ && (substr($1,2) in a){ print $2,$3 }' id.txt nr.fa > prot_names.txt
```

---

The resulting `prot_names.txt` file will look like below:

```
hypothetical protein
hypothetical protein
...
```

---

If you want to grep the whole lines containing protein names - use the following **grep** approach:

```
grep -Ff id.txt nr.fa > prot_names.txt
```

In this case `prot_names.txt` file will contain:

```
>KKP42119.1 hypothetical protein DDB_G027.......
>KKP65897.1 hypothetical protein DDB_G127.......
...
```

Answer (score 0):

in bash you can simply use grep to get the line that matches the search string:

`grep "KKP65897.1" database.txt`

Comment: I have >10000 names like "KKP65897.1", I cannot grep one by one. Is there a way to grep in batch?

Comment: what is the actual KEY you can lookup you info by? because if you don't have a primary key, then i don't see how you can do this